# jQuery UI 1.8.13 resizable() icon not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

In both jQuery 1.8.12 and 1.8.13 i no longer get the se handle icon which gets placed at the bottom right of the element to indicate this element is resizable.

**Check http://jsfiddle.net/wYcWU/**

If you switch the 1.8.13 to 1.8.11 then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in both 1.8.12/13 they added `background-image:url(data:);` to fix an IE issue as per ticket http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7233. Looking at firebug i see that `.ui-resizable-handle` is overriding the png background image of `ui-icon` which is the sprite image that is responsible for showing the se icon. This is definitely a bug. Check attached firebug screenshot.

It does work in the base theme as per Ali's answer because `ui-icon` is overriding `ui-resizable-handle` and not vise versa. So it's a theme issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use

ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

instead of

ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/start/jquery-ui.css

Comment: this has nothing to do with it and makes no difference. You are just referring to different theme names.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm not using the base theme. I'm using the start theme.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in javascript:

```
$('#test').resizable();
$('.ui-resizable-se').css({'height':'32px', 'width':'32px'});
```